# Negation in prolog query is not working

Tags: prolog, logic, negation

HI i have a simple knowledge database defined as:

```
carClass('X1','Oil','small').
carClass('X2','gas','big').
carClass('X3','Petrol','big').
carClass('X4','oil','small').
carClass('X5','Oil','small').
carClass('X6','gas','big').
```

I am trying to write a rule that will answer the query: *Display all carClass that runs on 'oil' and IS NOT 'big'.*

I am trying to implement it using:

```
OnOilButNotBig :-
   carClass(CarClass,'oil',_),
   carClass(CarClass,'oil', \+('big') ),
   write(CarClass).
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand the difference between a *predicate* and a *functor*.

If we oversimplify things a bit, a predicate is an identifier *at the top level*, so `carClass/3` is a predicate, `write/1` is a predicate and `onOilButNotBig/0` is. You can call a predicate. A predicate with filled in arguments is a *goal*.

A functor on the other hand is an identifier not on the top level. *Constants* are functors, *variables* are functors, and *functions with arguments* are functors. Examples of functors are `'X1'`, `'oil'` and `foo(X,bar,qux(2))`.

The negation expects a *goal*. `'big'` in this case is not a goal, in fact `\+('big')` itself is a functor.

You can only solve this by turning the condition **into a goal** and ensure you will call it. This can be done like:

```
onOilButNotBig :-
   carClass(CarClass,'oil',_),
   carClass(CarClass,'oil',X),
   \+(X = 'big'),
   write(CarClass).
```

Furthermore I do not really see why you call `carClass/3` twice. An equivalent and slightly more efficient program is the following:

```
onOilButNotBig :-
   carClass(CarClass,'oil',X),
   \+(X = 'big'),
   write(CarClass).
```

Finally as [@Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584662/67579) noted, you need to use names that start with a lowercase for predicates and functions.

Answer (score 1):

First things first!

- The code doesn't compile<sup>1</sup>.
  Why? Predicate names usually start with lowercase characters<sup>2</sup>.

  My advice: instead of `OnOilButNotBig` write `onOilButNotBig`!
- To express term inequality, use the right [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) goal(s), like so:

  ```
  onOilButNotBig :-
     dif(X, big),
     carClass(CarClass, oil, _),
     carClass(CarClass, oil, X),
     write(CarClass).
  ```
- As a side remark, there are a few more issues with your code:

  1. Use side-effect based I/O only when necessary.

     In most cases, it is preferable to use the interactive [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) for data input/output!

     ```
     onOilButNotBig(CarClass) :-
        dif(X, big),
        carClass(CarClass, oil, _),
        carClass(CarClass, oil, X).
     ```
  2. For the sake of readability, please do not use atoms like `'oil'` and `'Oil'`.

     Pick **one** and stick to it! I suggest `oil` (lowercase) which does not need escaping.
  3. The goal `carClass(CarClass, oil, _)` is *completely* redundant.

     Why? It is a generalisation of the close-by goal `carClass(CarClass,oil,X)`.

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** When using [b-prolog](/questions/tagged/b-prolog) 8.1, [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) 4.3.2, [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) 7.3.14, and [xsb](/questions/tagged/xsb) 3.6.


**Footnote 2:** Names *can* also starting with uppercase characters if the right (escaping with single-quotes) is utilized.


**Footnote 3:** In general, redundant goals are ok, but they suggest to me your code will likely not behave as intended.</sup>